# Can't save a temporary csv file to /home/app directory on heroku using R shiny app

Tags: heroku, shiny, shinyapps

I need to generate a temporary csv file on heroku /home/app directory and use it directly on my shiny application but the csv file is not being created in the directory when I try to check using heroku bash command there is no csv file exist in the directory. I don't need the file to be persistent in the server. I want it to be temporary use during processing only.

here is an example of the code to write the csv file to the directory

```
df <- c(0,0)
write.csv(df,"/home/app/test.csv")
```

Comment: "I need to generate a temporary csv file on heroku /home/app directory"—no you don't. Why do you think it has to go in `/home/app/`? Stay in your app's directory.

Comment: Thank you Chris for reaching out. But I don't understand I shouldn't do it or it's not possible? /home/app/ is where my app is.

Comment: Heroku apps are normally in `/app`, not `/home/app`. What makes you think it's in `/home/app`? "I don't understand I shouldn't do it or it's not possible?"—both. Any data you write needs to stay in the directory where Heroku puts your app. Normally, there is no need to use absolute paths at all.

Comment: I have tried write.csv(df, "test.csv"). It should write directly in the folder app but it does not work.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you think your application lives in `/home/app`. "but it does not work"—what does "does not work" mean? Are you getting an error? How are you checking to see if the file is there?

Comment: I have used getwd() and check the log to see the current working directory and it is /home/app. I am using heroku run bash command to check the folder using ls -l to see if the csv file is generated in the folder.

Comment: Okay, maybe Heroku now puts things into `/home/app` instead of `/app`. The point stands, though: don't use absolute paths. There's nothing stopping Heroku from moving the application directory to `/opt/app` or `/tmp/whatever`. Use relative paths. And see the linked duplicate.